# regex.h replace all char that are not [a..z] and [1..9] with " "

Tags: c

Could someone help me with this C code.
I would like to create a library in C ( to be used with Datastage ) that has 2 inputs params, First is the input string and the second the pattern ( abcd...z123456789 ) and one output.
Example : 
if I have the input String "qwertrty%$12"
with this pattern, the output should be "qwertrty12"

I found in internet this code, but is there anything more simple ? or how can I change it to just have 2 input and1 output ?
Thank You very Much for your help

```
 #ifndef __STR_REPLACE__
#define __STR_REPLACE__

#include <string.h>

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

int str_replace(const char *orig, const char *rep, const char *with,
    char **pbuf, size_t *pbuf_sz);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif

int str_replace(const char *orig, const char *rep, const char *with,
    char **pbuf, size_t *pbuf_sz) {
    char *ins;    // the next insert point
    char *tmp;    // varies
    int len_rep;  // length of rep
    int len_with; // length of with
    int len_front; // distance between rep and end of last rep
    int count;    // number of replacements

    if (!orig)
        return -2;
    if (!rep || !(len_rep = strlen(rep)))
        return -2;
    if (!(ins = strstr(orig, rep)))
        return -1;
    if (!with)
        return -2;
    if (!pbuf)
        return -2;
    len_with = strlen(with);

    for (count = 0; ((tmp = strstr(ins, rep)) != NULL); ++count) {
        ins = tmp + len_rep;
    }
    size_t buf_sz = strlen(orig) + (len_with - len_rep) * count + 1;
    if (pbuf_sz)
        *pbuf_sz = buf_sz;
    if (*pbuf) {
        tmp = *pbuf = (char*) realloc(*pbuf, buf_sz);
        memset(*pbuf, 0, buf_sz);
    } else {
        tmp = *pbuf = (char*) calloc(buf_sz, sizeof(char));
    }

    while (count--) {
        ins = strstr(orig, rep);
        len_front = ins - orig;
        tmp = strncpy(tmp, orig, len_front) + len_front;
        tmp = strcpy(tmp, with) + len_with;
        orig += len_front + len_rep; // move to next "end of rep"
    }
    strcpy(tmp, orig);
    return 0;
}

#endif
```

Comment: You don't need a *regex*. Simply walk the input string one character at a time and change/copy it.

Comment: This seems to be a source file but you use inclusion guards. Do you intent to include that code into other files?

Comment: Do you want to change the string in place or make a second string that contains the result?

Comment: well, have the output of the library with the result

Comment: Here is an O(n^2) version https://onlinegdb.com/ryhv8dhwI

Comment: If you only want to always allow digits and upper and lower case letters then here is an O(n) version https://onlinegdb.com/r1fwtu3wU

Comment: Fantastic, thank you :)

Comment: Another question please ... if now I would like to just keep all ascii , that are > chr(30). in the Loop, I have to compare *string_ptr with ? I tried to modify it but with no success. Sorry for this question and thank you

Comment: I did this but it is filtering more char, like ä£®#@

Comment: char* FilterHexaChar(char* pStr)
{
    // Work variables declaration
    char *result = pStr;

    for(const char *string_ptr = pStr; *string_ptr; string_ptr++)
    {
            if ((int)string_ptr[0] != 26 )
            {
                *result++ = *string_ptr;
            }
    }
    *result = '\0';

    // Return Input String : pStr  formatted, removing all Strange Char
    return pStr;
}